# Configuration which allows to disable cloud stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, dynamic-loading, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a spring boot application which has two functionalities Http requests and kafka Messages handling. I want this application to run in mode which is enabled from application.yml i.e if the user wants to enable it only for http requests then kafka should not be connected.

I could achieve this using normal spring boot kafka plugin by disabling auto configure using the following property at @KafkaListener,

> autoStartup="${module.put:false}"

Now we are trying to move to cloud stream and the only way I found to disable it by removing the libraries of cloud stream and binder. Is there any better way to disable it using properties with auto config mode or is there any manual config option available?

Answer (score 9):

I found I could disable the attempt by `AdminClient` to connect to (down) brokers through the use of a "build" spring profile, then in application-build.yml, exclude the relevant configurations:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceConfiguration
      - org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration
```

This is tested on Spring Cloud Stream 3.1.3.

Comment: I have searched far and wide for this answer, and this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Cloud Stream bindings also have `autoStartup` properties.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties

> **autoStartup**
>
> Signals if this consumer needs to be started automatically
>
> Default: true.

Comment: but this still starts AdminClientConfig and tries to connect to kafka. I want this entire setup to be disabled

Comment: Use `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics=false` to stop that.

Comment: it still tries to connect even after adding this property..

my config is here 

spring:
    cloud:
      stream:
        kafka:
          binder:
            brokers: localhost:9092
            autoCreateTopics: false
        bindings:
          input:
            binder: kafka
            destination: Test
            content-type: text/plain
            group: EXTERNAL
            consumer:
              autoStartup: false

Comment: Oh, right; yes I see - I suggest you ask for a new feature against [the binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues).